# How can I delete a release version of a 2nd Generation Package in Salesforce?

Tags: managed-package, 2gp, patch

Our 2nd Generation Package recently passed security review under the version 'PackageName@0.1.0-3'. Subsequently, we made minor changes to the package, including updating icons and modifying objects. However, due to an oversight, we accidentally created a new version 'PackageName@0.2.0-1' and released it without setting the proper ancestorId as intended.

Now, when attempting to create a version by specifying the correct ancestorId, we encounter the following error message:
'Can’t create package version. The ancestor version [PackageName@0.1.0-3] you specified isn’t the highest released package version. Set the ancestor version to 0.2.0, and try creating the package version again. You can also specify --skipancestorcheck to override the ancestry requirement.'

Additionally, when trying to delete the release version, we encounter another error:
'Can’t delete the package version. Second-generation managed packages that have been promoted to released can’t be deleted.'

Could someone please provide guidance on the best solution to this issue?

Comment: Check this: [Delete a Second-Generation Managed Package or Package Version](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_package_deletion.htm)

Comment: @TusharJadav yeah we cannot delete released package version but is there any other way to create the patch version for my package 0.1.0-3

Comment: Raise a case with Salesforce Support.

Comment: What's weird is you should be able to create version branches, so why there's a grumble about the highest released package version isn't clear. Perhaps you need to [edit] your question and add the visualization of the package version tree?